# Custom TextView not refreshed only on phone

Tags: android, textview

I created a custom TextView that is displayed in a GridView. When the user taps on the TextView, a black circle has to be displayed in the center of this TextView. Actually this used to work fine on my tablet (an ASUS TF300, something like that). FYI all clicked textviews are then saved in a local database and can be loaded again.

I also tested that on a smartphone. Weird thing : the black circle is not displayed after a tap. However I know that it works because the black circles are well displayed if I save my UI and reload it again.

Did I miss something ?

Please find the code of the custom TextView below.

```
public class ChordItemTextView extends TextView {

// Properties
private ChordItem item;
public void setChordItem(ChordItem item)
{
    this.item = item;
}

private Paint fretPaint;
private Paint chordPaint;
private Paint textPaint;
private int paperColor;

public ChordItemTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.Init(context);
}

public ChordItemTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    this.Init(context);
}

private void Init(Context context)
{
    // Resources retrieval
    Resources myResources  = getResources();

    this.fretPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    this.fretPaint.setColor(myResources.getColor(R.color.fretColor));

    this.chordPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    this.chordPaint.setColor(myResources.getColor(R.color.fretColor));

    this.textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    this.textPaint.setColor(myResources.getColor(R.color.fretIndication));
    this.textPaint.setTextSize(myResources.getDimension(R.dimen.fretFontSize));

    this.paperColor = myResources.getColor(R.color.bgColor);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    // paper color
    canvas.drawColor(this.paperColor);

    // fret line drawing
    canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight() / 2, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight() / 2, this.fretPaint);
    canvas.drawLine((float) (getMeasuredWidth() * 0.99), 0, (float) (getMeasuredWidth() * 0.99), getMeasuredHeight(), this.fretPaint);
    if (this.item.getFretNumber() == 0)
    {
        canvas.drawLine((float)( getMeasuredWidth() * 0.95), 0, (float)( getMeasuredWidth() * 0.95), getMeasuredHeight(), this.fretPaint);
    }

    // "tap" drawing
    if (this.item.getIsPushed())
    {
        canvas.drawCircle(getMeasuredWidth() / 2, getMeasuredHeight() / 2, getMeasuredHeight() / 4, this.chordPaint);
    }

    // fret number drawing
    if (this.item.getStringNumber() == 1)
    {
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(this.item.getFretNumber()), getMeasuredWidth() / 2, getMeasuredHeight(), this.textPaint);
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

Comment: " the black circles are well displayed if I save my UI and reload it again" what do you mean?

Comment: Can you post your event listener?

Comment: m vai : I save the position of the textviews I tapped in the database. Then I re-load those positions and re-display the black circles. So when I tap, the black circles are not displayed. But when I load them, they are well displayed.

Comment: Alberto :
 GridView cgd = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.chordgridview);
 cgd.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
   updateChordItem(position);
  }
 });